# Push values to a map when key is already exisitng in a map

Tags: java, dictionary, grails

I have declared a map as below:

```
 Map<String, String[]> test = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

I have a variable empnames which is an array and deptname is a String and i have declared the deptname and empnames as below:

```
 String deptname = ['Department']
 String empnames = [['Test1']['Test2']]

 if (deptname != null)
        {
            if (test.containsKey(deptname))
                {
                    ///
                }
                else
                {

                    test.put(deptname, new String[]{empnames}); 
                }
            }
```

If the test map already contains deptname key then what condition i should write in if condition to append new values to department?

Comment: `String deptname = ['Department']` is valid code but probably isn't doing what you think it is.  More likely you want `String deptname = 'Department'`.  Separate from that, `String empnames = [['Test1']['Test2']]` isn't really valid code.  That is going to try and resolve a property named `Test2` on an instance of `String`, which of course does not exist (the `Test2` property does not exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> departmentList;
    if(test.containsKey(key)){
        // if the key has already been used, then and add a new value to it
        list = test.get(key);
        list.add(value);
        test.put(key, list);
    } else {
        // if the key hasn't been used yet, then create a new ArrayList<String> object, add the value
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(value);
        test.put(key, list);
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to run your code and i get errors as my map decalration is different.Do i have to change the map declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged for [grails], I assume a Groovy answer is appropriate too.  You can use a Map with `.withDefault{ ... }` to provide the content in case the key is missing.  E.g.

```
def data = [["x", ["a", "b"]], ["x", ["c", "d"]]]

def test = [:].withDefault{[]} // XXX

data.each{ k, vs ->
    test[k].addAll(vs) // if there is no key `k`, create an empty array, so `.addAll` just works
}

println(test.inspect())
// => ['x':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new methods in Java 8 like [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) to add new entry if key is not present and [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to append values to an existing key of a map.

An example would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String[]> test = new HashMap<>();
  String deptname = "Department";
  String[] empnames = {"Test1", "Test2"};

  if (deptname != null){
       test.putIfAbsent(deptname, empnames);
       test.computeIfPresent(deptname, (dept, value) -> {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value));
            list.add("Test3");
            value = list.toArray(value);
            return value;
       });
  }

  for(String s : test.get("Department")){
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Here the `putIfAbsent` tests if the key is present, if not adds a new key-value entry. The `computeIfAbsent` on the other hand tests if the key is present, if yes it computes the new value for the existing key-value entry.

The output of the above code is:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

This is because initially the key `Department` was not present in the map `test`, so it was added to it along with the value `empnames` as an array.

In the second operation the method `computeIfPresent` checked that the key `Department` was already in the map so it appended the new String `Test3` to existing value array of `[Test1, Test2]`.

The same can be done for an `List` instead of an array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<String, List<String>> test = new HashMap<>();
       String deptname = "Department";
       List<String> empnames = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2"));

       if (deptname != null){
           test.putIfAbsent(deptname, empnames);
           test.computeIfPresent(deptname, (dept, value) -> {
               value.add("Test3");
               return value;
           });
       }

       for(String s : test.get("Department")){
           System.out.println(s);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, this would be easier if you had an ArrayList instead of String[].
But since you have a String[], you will have to make a new array of old_array's_size + list_to_add and copy over the values from the old array into the new one plus the new value you want to append.

So inside of your if statement:

```
String [] oldList = test.get(deptName);
String[] newList = new String[oldList.length + empnames.length]; //Make a new array with enough space for the previous values at deptname but also the new ones you want to add

//Put all of the values from the existing value at deptname into a new array
for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++)
newList[i] = oldList[i];

//Put all of the values from the list of values you want to add into the new array
for (int i = 0; i < empnames.length; i++)
newList[oldList.length + i] = empnames[i];

test.put(deptname, newList); //Put the completed list back into the map
```

Again, if you used some kind of List this would be easier. One good reason besides being able to append is that you can easily sort it alphabetically using Collections.sort.